# Ansible Customization for Linux

Tags: linux, ansible, vcenter, ansible-awx

I want to set the password on VM (Windows & Linux) during customization hence using 'customization' option from vmware_guest module to achieve that. It is working perfect for VMs deployed from windows template but that does not work for Linux VMs. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
    customization:        
         hostname: "{{ vm_name }}"      
         password: "{{ my_pass }}"  
      wait_for_customization: yes  
      wait_for_ip_address: True  
      state: poweredon
```

Comment: Does your Linux template image have Perl installed?

Comment: `... but that does not work ...` is never a self sufficient explanation to describe your problem. What is the expected behavior? What do you get instead? Are there any errors/warning messages you could get from ansible (possibly using `-vvv` on ansible playbook command line)?

Comment: The Linux template does have perl installed "perl-5.16.3-295.el7.x86_64". The customization works on the VM but only the password is not set. My question is whether the 'password' parameter on customization is only mean to set the administrator account password or will it also set the root password for Linux VMs?

Answer (score 0):

While searching on the internet came across a VMware community thread which says customization of linux root password is not possible, there are other blogs which iterates same. I will have to probably make use of user module in ansible as a workaround.
VMware community thread: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/252997